# Learning about constraints in Alloy

Tags: alloy

I'm exploring Alloy for my company hackathon. We have a complicated data model, and my goal is to generate pictures of correct examples so that new employees can see them and learn about our application. I've managed to stumble along and generate some pictures, but I'm having trouble expressing the following idea:

> A **role** can grant access to one or more **fields**. A **user** has one or more roles, and can access zero or more fields. A user can access a field if and only if the user has a role which grants access to that field.

Here's one of many attempts with incorrect syntax; hopefully it shows what misconceptions I have about how Alloy works.

```
sig Role { grantsAccess: some Field }
sig User { 
    has: some Role,
    canAccess: Field    
}{
    all u: User |
    f: Field in u.canAccess iff some r: Role in u.has | f in r.grantsAccess
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
-- A role can grant access to one or more fields. 

sig Role { grant : some Field } 
sig Field {}

-- A user has one or more roles, 
-- and can access zero or more fields. 

sig User {
    roles : set Role
}

-- A user can access a field    

pred User.canAccess[ field : Field ] {

    -- if and only if the user has a role 
    -- which grants access to that field.

    some role : this.roles | field in role.grant

    // alternative:
    // some ( this.roles & grant.field )
}

run ex1 { 
    some u : User, f : Field {
        u.canAccess[f]
    }
}
```

Comment: I would put that a user has "some Role ", and a Role grants access to a "set of Field".
Yet I understand why you did it that way, the specification sounds somewhat incomplete. Why would a user have access to zero or more field instead of one or more field, knowing that a user has one or more role and that a role grants access to one or more fields...

Comment: I tried to follow his specification as _literal_ as possible. Notice that the comments are exactly what he specified. I likely would not say a role has `some` field. In practice that makes the system extremely awkward to initialize/setup.

Comment: Yeah we agree. As per the specification though, I'd define a user to have `some` Role. This would mean that a user can never access zero fields despite the specification saying otherwise ...

Comment: But those are the insights about your specifications that the model should inform you off :-)